# ¿Como selecciono un elemento aleatorio de un conjunto en pyhton?

Tags: python, random, conjuntos

Quiero seleccionar un elemento aleadorio de un conjunto, he intentado de la siguiente manera pero me lanza un excepcion, como podria arreglarse?

```
import random

a = {(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)}
b = random.choice(a)
```

Comment: Que te parecería trabajar con tuplas o listas en lugar de conjuntos? Ese error me paso una vez y CREO que se debe a que internamente choice elige una posicion aleatoria en la secuencia dada, y los conjuntos no tienen posiciones. Dale un vistaso a esta pregunta (en ingles): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837729/random-choice-from-set-python

Comment: Parece que la solución sería usar random.sample en su lugar, pero [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3.9/library/random.html#random.sample) indica que en el futuro esto ya no funcionará.

Comment: El enlace ha sido de gran ayuda, muchas gracias

Comment: Random.sample funciona correctamente, pero parece que transformar el conjunto en una lista o tupla y despues usar choice de la siguiente manera es mas eficaz. `b = random.choice(tuple(a))`

Answer (score 4):

El error se debe a que `random.choice` opera sobre un elemento *indexable*, es decir, uno donde tenga sentido decir `elemento[i]`. Cómo estás usando un `set`, que no es indexable, se produce el error

```
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

**Solución**

La más obvia es convertir el `set` en una lista y aplicarle `random.choice`. Si vas a repetir el mismo proceso sobre el mismo set, conviene hacer la conversión sólo una vez al comenzar.

```
import random

a = {(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)}
b = random.choice(list(a))
print(b)
```

produce:

```
(3, 4)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Buenas una manera es recorrer el conjunto...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
a = {(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)}
x=[]
for j in a:
    x.append(j)
b = random.choice(x)
print(b)
```

Comment: Esto no selecciona un elemento del conjunto.

Comment: Tu respuesta estaría mejor si esta linea `b = random.choice(x)` la sacaras del bucle for, ya que se ejecuta al cohete varias veces cuando alcanza con una. Incluso así, es mas facil y mas legible convertir el conjunto en lista con el constructor list (que es lo que hace Candid Moe).

Comment: Tienes razón. Gracias